# Confounding by indication in observational cohort study: how to address?

Tags: survival, cox-model, confounding

**Background**

We are conducting a register based cohort study into effect of pain killer medication in cancer patients. Index date is date of diagnosis of early cancer in a defined study population.  We have information on baseline clinical characteristics and type of treatment over followup, though only sufficient information to model them as fixed in time covariates. Outcomes are death from cancer and all cause death.
Explanatory variable of interest is exposure to pain killer medication which we can get from ATC codes of prescribed drugs for each individual.  We plan to derrive Hazard ratios from a Cox model, or similar.

**Issue**

The problem I am concerned about is ***confounding by indication***, since sicker patients are more likely to be given pain killers / more pain killers / stronger pain killers etc.

**My thoughts of possible solutions**

1. Stratify or model the severity of disease over followup time. However, we do not have such information. We do know that at baseline the disease severity is "similar" as per our patient population. Am I right that, at least in part, baseline covariates and planned course of treatment will account for (projected) disease severity over followup? If so, that might be defensible to adjust hazard ratios representing the effect of pain killer exposure groups on risk of death?
2. Exclude patients close to death from cancer e.g. within 6 months on the basis that those patients will likely be given more pain killers. That seems wasteful to me and even though these patients might die soon (our outcome) the intake of painkillers might still affect time to death in those sicker patients.
3. Fit a smooth term of time as an explanatory variable which represents patients health generally deteriorating over time. It's a bit iffy and I'm not sure whether the Cox model implicitly handles this already?
4. Change to an active comparator design instead of comparing amount of pain killers of the same type of drug.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if it helps, can you please provide causal diagram of what you are trying to solve. Please take a look at https://www.dagitty.net/dags.html

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. However I don't think dags would be helpful to answer my question (though if I am mistaken, I would gladly appreciate advice on how they can be used in this context).